# Python Invalid Int () Error

Tags: python, typeerror

```
import turtle
index = 0 #to traverse through list
turtle.setup(800,600) # Change the width of the drawing to 800px and the 
height to 600px.
wn = turtle.Screen()
sammy = turtle.Turtle()

inFile = open('mystery.txt','r')
outFile=inFile.read()
outFileContent = outFile.split ()
while index != (len(outFileContent)): #for item in the list
    if str(outFileContent [index]) == "UP": #if the current index goes up, pen up
        sammy.penup()

    elif str(outFileContent [index]) == "DOWN": #else if its down, pen down
        sammy.pendown ()

    elif outFileContent[index].isalpha () == False : #if its a number, go to 
those coordinates
        sammy.goto (int(outFileContent[index]),int(outFileContent[index+1])) #convert from str to int

    index+=1 #goes to next value in list


    print ((int(outFileContent [index]), int(outFileContent[index+1]))) #make sure its printing the right coordinates

inFile.close()
wn.mainloop ()
```

So this program is supposed to open a list and then make the turtle do the commands on the list. If the line reads UP, then the turtle puts the pen up. If the line reads DOWN, then the turtle puts the pen down. If the line is a pair of numbers, then the turtle goes to those coordinates. Here are the contents of the file "mystery.txt":

```
UP
-218 185
DOWN
```

However, when I run the program, it outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Yariel\Google 
Drive\Coding\Python\Scripts\Files\turtle_file_mystery_shape.py", line 23, in <module>
print ((int(outFileContent [index]), int(outFileContent[index+1]))) #make 
sure its printing the right coordinates
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'DOWN'
```

I have no idea why it's turning down into an integer which I never specified. (If you look at the coordinates in the print statement, it outputs the right coordinates).
So any help?  on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code with a debugger and check the values?

Comment: Take a close look at what is in `outFileContent` and what your code expects of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates are a special input case. You need to increment `index` by an additional `1` to accommodate the second `int`.

```
# ...
elif outFileContent[index].isalpha () == False : #if its a number, go to those coordinates
    sammy.goto (int(outFileContent[index]),int(outFileContent[index+1])) #convert from str to int
    # move print to here; indexing changed
    print ((int(outFileContent [index]), int(outFileContent[index+1])))
    # additional increment to index to accommodate second int
    index += 1

index+=1 #goes to next value in list
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than patch your code, I suggest you rethink it.  The rework below process the mystery file line by line, instead of all at once, and is hopefully easier for you to augment and debug:

```
import sys
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
# Set width of the drawing to 800px and height to 600px
screen.setup(800, 600)

sammy = Turtle()

commands = {'UP': sammy.penup, 'DOWN': sammy.pendown}

with open('mystery.txt') as inFile:

    for line in inFile:
        content = line.rstrip().split()

        if len(content) == 1 and content[0] in commands:

            commands[content[0]]()  # eg. UP and DOWN

        elif len(content) == 2 and not content[0].isalpha() and not content[1].isalpha():

            # seem to be numbers, convert from str to int and go to those coordinates
            sammy.goto(int(content[0]), int(content[1]))

        else:
            print("Invalid input:", content, file=sys.stderr)

screen.mainloop()
```